# Comparison not working

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm using IONIC, and TypeScript 2.4.2, but my comparison is not working.
Is this a bug of this TS version?

Some informations:

  IONIC Version     : 3.20.0

  NPM Version       : 5.6.0

  Angular Version   : 5.0.3

  Typescript Version: 2.4.2

This is my code:

```
let utilizaDesconto: boolean = (this.objSCON.SCON_UtilizaDescontoItem as boolean);

//THIS ALERT DISPLAY "false"
alert(utilizaDesconto);

if (!utilizaDesconto)
  alert("should display this message");
else
  alert("but display this!");
```

Comment: what does `this.objSCON.SCON_UtilizaDescontoItem` contain?

Comment: Highly unlikely this is a TS issue, `this.objSCON.SCON_UtilizaDescontoItem` probably contains the `string` `"false"` not the value `false`. This does what you describe: `let utilizaDesconto = "false";
if (!utilizaDesconto)
  alert("should display this message");
else
  alert("but display this!");`

Comment: this.objSCON.SCON_UtilizaDescontoItem is a boolean type, is a field of my interface. The content is false, boolean value

Comment: then why are you asserting to boolean again?

Comment: because [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20str%3Aboolean%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0Alet%20utilizaDesconto%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20(str%20as%20boolean)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FTHIS%20ALERT%20DISPLAY%20%22false%22%0D%0Aalert(utilizaDesconto)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(!utilizaDesconto)%0D%0A%20%20alert(%22should%20display%20this%20message%22)%3B%0D%0Aelse%0D%0A%20%20alert(%22but%20display%20this!%22)%3B) works

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, you right, sorry. But this variable is "boolean" in my interface, but the value is filled by a select in SQLite. Now i'm casting the value to bool. Thanks to help.